# parseString not working for me in xml.sax (Python)

Tags: python, xml, sax

I need to validate xml but the code comes in a variable (str), not from a file.

So I figured this would be easy to do with xml.sax. But I can't get it to work for me. It works fine when parsing a file, but I get a strange error when parsing a string.

Here's my test-code:

```
from xml.sax import make_parser, parseString
import os

filename = os.path.join('.', 'data', 'data.xml')
xmlstr = "<note>\n<to>Mary</to>\n<from>Jane</from>\n<heading>Reminder</heading>\n<body>Go to the zoo</body>\n</note>"


def parsefile(file):
    parser = make_parser()
    parser.parse(file)


def parsestr(xmlstr):
    parser = make_parser()
    parseString(xmlstr.encode('utf-8'), parser)


try:
    parsefile(filename)
    print("%s is well-formed" % filename)
except Exception as e:
    print("%s is NOT well-formed! %s" % (filename, e))


try:
    parsestr(xmlstr)
    print("%s is well-formed" % ('xml string'))
except Exception as e:
    print("%s is NOT well-formed! %s" % ('xml string', e))
```

When executing the script, I get this:

```
./data/data.xml is well-formed
xml string is NOT well-formed! 'ExpatParser' object has no attribute 'processingInstruction'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `parseString` is supposed to be a [`ContentHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.handler.html#contenthandler-objects), not a parser. Because you're passing in the wrong type of object, it doesn't have the expected methods.

You're expected to subclass `ContentHandler` and then handle the SAX events as necessary. In this case, you're not actually trying to extract any information from the document, so you could use the base `ContentHandler` class:

```
from xml.sax import parseString, SAXParseException
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

xmlstr = "<note>\n<to>Mary</to>\n<from>Jane</from>\n<heading>Reminder</heading>\n<body>Go to the zoo</body>\n</note>"

try:
    parseString(xmlstr, ContentHandler())
    print("document is well formed")
except SAXParseException as err:
    print("document is not well-formed:", err)
```